Depth image(pyramid) transition syncronization issues
Following the Vulkan guide(https://vkguide.dev/docs/gpudriven/compute_culling/) (extra-engine branch), and having problems with depth pyramid image transition. Vulkan gives this error
\>VkImage 0xd897d90000000016 is a depth pyramid base image
Is there any problem with the guide source code?
[ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout ] Object 0: handle = 0x2536ff37530, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x4dae5635 | vkQueueSubmit(): pSubmits[0].pCommandBuffers[0] command buffer VkCommandBuffer 0x2536ff37530[] expects VkImage 0xd897d90000000016[] (subresource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0) to be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL--instead, the current layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED.
code from the guide, where presumably the transition problem happens

void VulkanEngine::reduce_depth(VkCommandBuffer cmd)
{
    vkutil::VulkanScopeTimer timer(cmd, _profiler, "Depth Reduce");

    VkImageMemoryBarrier depthReadBarriers[] =
    {
        vkinit::image_barrier(_depthImage._image, VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT),
    };

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, depthReadBarriers);

    vkCmdBindPipeline(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, _depthReducePipeline);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < depthPyramidLevels; ++i)
    {
        VkDescriptorImageInfo destTarget;
        destTarget.sampler = _depthSampler;
        destTarget.imageView = depthPyramidMips[i];
        destTarget.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;

        VkDescriptorImageInfo sourceTarget;
        sourceTarget.sampler = _depthSampler;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            sourceTarget.imageView = _depthImage._defaultView;
            sourceTarget.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        }
        else {
// DEPTH pyramid current layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED by vulkan validation layer
            sourceTarget.imageView = depthPyramidMips[i - 1];
            sourceTarget.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
        }

        VkDescriptorSet depthSet;
        vkutil::DescriptorBuilder::begin(_descriptorLayoutCache, get_current_frame().dynamicDescriptorAllocator)
            .bind_image(0, &destTarget, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE, VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT)
            .bind_image(1, &sourceTarget, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT)
            .build(depthSet);

        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, _depthReduceLayout, 0, 1, &depthSet, 0, nullptr);

        uint32_t levelWidth = depthPyramidWidth >> i;
        uint32_t levelHeight = depthPyramidHeight >> i;
        if (levelHeight < 1) levelHeight = 1;
        if (levelWidth < 1) levelWidth = 1;

        DepthReduceData reduceData = { glm::vec2(levelWidth, levelHeight) };

        vkCmdPushConstants(cmd, _depthReduceLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT, 0, sizeof(reduceData), &reduceData);
        vkCmdDispatch(cmd, getGroupCount(levelWidth, 32), getGroupCount(levelHeight, 32), 1);


        VkImageMemoryBarrier reduceBarrier = vkinit::image_barrier(_depthPyramid._image, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT);

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, &reduceBarrier);
    }

    VkImageMemoryBarrier depthWriteBarrier = vkinit::image_barrier(_depthImage._image, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT);

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT, VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, &depthWriteBarrier);

}

Mainly, I suppose, the problem could be in reduce_depth or based on forward/shadow render pass creation (I tried to fix this problem by changing dependencies info in forward/shadow passes, now working for now).

Seems that pipeline barriers do nothing more than Vulkan itself for synchronization(removed all calls to vkCmdPipelineBarrier in reduce depth and in the render loop, and got the same debug error). Maybe something wrong in render passes creation.

Release mode(without validation layer) got working(has other problems with render result, but it's rendering)
